# Asp .Net Core Socket

Tags: asp.net-core

I made a backend with ASP .Net Core, first i made some Controllers for HTTP requests and they all worked fine, but i wanted to integrate a Socket to connect with with my Unity Game. I got the Socket working, but since i added the Socket the HTTP Controllers dont work anymore.
I think it has something to do with the Port but i m not able to figure out how to fix that.
Here is the Socket Code

```cs
public static void ServerSocket()
{
    Console.WriteLine("TEXT");

    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 1302);
    listener.Start();
    while (true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection");
        TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        Console.WriteLine("Client Accepted");
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            int recv = 0;
            foreach (byte b in buffer)
            {
                if (b != 0)
                {
                    recv++;
                }
            }

            string request = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, recv);
            Console.WriteLine("request received");
            sw.WriteLine("Hello darkness my old");
            sw.Flush();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong");
            sw.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(sr.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I call that function in Startup.

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseHsts();
    }
    
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseMvc();
    Thread newThread = new Thread(ServerSocketApp.ServerSocket);
    newThread.Start();
}
```

Comment: Need to see the startup also.

Answer (score 0):

TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient() is a blocking method, which will prevent the rest of the code from executing.
Please try using [TcpListener.AcceptTcpClientAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.accepttcpclientasync?view=netcore-3.1) instead.

Edit: the other guy is also right, putting that code in a different Thread is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `while(true) { ... }`, which will cause execution to spin and never return back to `Startup()`, thus causing `Startup()` to halt as well.

Consider moving this socket code to a background thread. See [Thread.Start in System.Threading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.start?view=netcore-3.1) as one way you can make this happen.

Comment: i m dumb right now, should i call it like this?: 

Thread newThread = new Thread(ServerSocketApp.ServerSocket);
newThread.Start();

Comment: @Olotolo that should work if ServerSocketApp.ServerSocket is a ThreadProc with the proper signature.